# Problem with matplotlib date formatting and conversion from epoch time: OverlowError: int too big to convert

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime-conversion

The time on the x-axis of my plot is in seconds since the epoch, and I want to convert them to "Year-Month-Day Hour:Minute" format. I follow the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/api/date_demo.html), and I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andreas/src/masiri/booking_algorythm/simple_booking.py", line 277, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/andreas/src/masiri/booking_algorythm/simple_booking.py", line 273, in main
    accepted_list_of_bookings, accepted_bookings_a = process_booking_requests(randomized_list_of_bookings)
  File "/home/andreas/src/masiri/booking_algorythm/simple_booking.py", line 257, in process_booking_requests
    price = calculate_price_for_booking(trip_request, sequential_trip_requests,
  File "/home/andreas/src/masiri/booking_algorythm/simple_booking.py", line 226, in calculate_price_for_booking
    old_price = turn_booking_into_charging_plan(start_time, end_time, old_bookings_list)
  File "/home/andreas/src/masiri/booking_algorythm/simple_booking.py", line 209, in turn_booking_into_charging_plan
    plot_solution(sub_metric_v, soc_plot, charge_plot, discharge_plot, bookings_list, instability_ranges)
  File "/home/andreas/src/masiri/booking_algorythm/simple_booking.py", line 195, in plot_solution
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
  File "/home/andreas/src/masiri/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 249, in autofmt_xdate
    for label in ax.get_xticklabels(which=which):
  File "/home/andreas/src/masiri/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 73, in wrapper
    return get_method(self)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andreas/src/masiri/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1381, in get_ticklabels
    return self.get_majorticklabels()
  File "/home/andreas/src/masiri/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1345, in get_majorticklabels
    self._update_ticks()
  File "/home/andreas/src/masiri/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1191, in _update_ticks
    major_labels = self.major.formatter.format_ticks(major_locs)
  File "/home/andreas/src/masiri/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 233, in format_ticks
    return [self(value, i) for i, value in enumerate(values)]
  File "/home/andreas/src/masiri/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 233, in <listcomp>
    return [self(value, i) for i, value in enumerate(values)]
  File "/home/andreas/src/masiri/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 640, in __call__
    result = num2date(x, self.tz).strftime(self.fmt)
  File "/home/andreas/src/masiri/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 533, in num2date
    return _from_ordinalf_np_vectorized(x, tz).tolist()
  File "/home/andreas/src/masiri/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2328, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/home/andreas/src/masiri/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2411, in _vectorize_call
    outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
  File "/home/andreas/src/masiri/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 354, in _from_ordinalf
    np.timedelta64(int(np.round(x * MUSECONDS_PER_DAY)), 'us'))
OverflowError: int too big to convert
```

This is my code (I will supply a minimal example, but as far as I can see, this is purely time conversion related).

```
def plot_solution(data, soc_plot,charge_plot, discharge_plot, bookings=None, boundaries=None):
    my_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    fig, ax_left = plt.subplots()
    ax_right = ax_left.twinx()
    ax_left.xaxis.set_major_formatter(my_fmt)
    ax_right.xaxis.set_major_formatter(my_fmt)
    time_axis = data["time"]

    ax_right.plot(time_axis, soc_plot, label="State of Charge")
    ax_left.plot(time_axis, data["price"], label="price (€/kWs)")
    ax_left.plot(time_axis, data["price_co2"], label="price including CO_2 costs (€/kWs)")
    #ax_right.plot(data["time"], charge_plot, label="charge")
    #ax_right.plot(data["time"], discharge_plot, label="discharge")
    bookings_flag = True
    if bookings is not None:
        for booking in bookings:
            if bookings_flag:
                ax_left.axvspan(booking["start"], booking["start"] + booking["duration"], facecolor='0.4', alpha=0.5, label="booking")
                bookings_flag = False
            else:
                ax_left.axvspan(booking["start"], booking["start"] + booking["duration"], facecolor='0.4', alpha=0.5, label="booking")
    boundaries_flag = True
    if boundaries is not None:
        for boundary in boundaries:
            if boundaries_flag:
                ax_left.axvspan(time_axis[boundary["start"]], time_axis[boundary["end"]], facecolor='0.9', alpha=0.5, label="boundary")
                boundaries_flag = False
            else:
                ax_left.axvspan(time_axis[boundary["start"]], time_axis[boundary["end"]], facecolor='0.9', alpha=0.5)
    ax_left.set_xlabel("time in seconds")
    ax_left.set_ylabel("price in €/kWs", color="blue")
    ax_right.set_ylabel("State of Charge (SoC), normalized", color="black")
    legend_1 = ax_left.legend(loc=2, borderaxespad=1.)
    legend_1.remove()
    ax_right.legend(loc=1, borderaxespad=1.)
    ax_right.add_artist(legend_1)
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    plt.show(block=True)
```

Here is an example of my time_axis data:

```
>>> time_axis
array([1635905700, 1635906600, 1635907500, 1635908400, 1635909300,
       1635910200, 1635911100, 1635912000, 1635912900, 1635913800,
```

Comment: Please give a few examples of what is in data[‘time’]. You say it’s seconds since the epoch but don’t show how you convert it to a date that Matplotlib will accept. Just running autofmt_date won’t convert a list of floats to meaningful dates

Comment: @JodyKlymak done. Perhaps that is the issue already? I was under the impression that the conversion was done by matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates in Matplotlib are stored as days since 1970 (if using Matplotlb >=3.5, the epoch was 0000 before).  So if you want to use something like `plot_date` on straight floats you can if you convert the floats from seconds to days.  However, better is probably to convert to datetime64.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl

time = np.array([1635905700, 1635906600, 1635907500, 1635908400, 1635909300,
       1635910200, 1635911100, 1635912000, 1635912900, 1635913800,])
y = np.arange(10)

plt.rcParams['date.converter'] = 'concise'

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, layout='constrained')
ax[0].plot(time/24/3600, y)
ax[0].xaxis_date()

ax[1].plot(time.astype('datetime64[s]'), y)

plt.show()
```

Note that I've also used the concise date converter https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/date_concise_formatter.html but that is just aesthetics.

`xaxis_date` (or `ax.plot_date` or `fig.autofmt_xdate`) are just short forms to set the units on the xaxis to datetime.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I went the way of converting to datetime64, and that worked nicely.